# rubymonk "all elements in an array are Fixnum"?

Tags: ruby

http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1/problems/148-array_of_fixnum

Ruby monk suggests:

```
def array_of_fixnums?(array)
  array.all? { |x| x.is_a? Fixnum }
end
```

That is fine and all, however the following code works in irb 1.9.2 but fails when rubymonk passes an empty array:

```
def array_of_fixnums?(array)
  result = false
  array.each { |n|
    if n.is_a? Fixnum
      result = true
    else
      result = false
    end }
  result
end
```

here is the irb output:

```
1.9.2-p320 :001 > array_of_fixnums? []
 => false
```

and here is what rubymonk says about my solution:

```
returns 'true' for [1,2,3] ✔
returns 'false' for ['a',1,:b] ✔
returns 'true' for []
    RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
    expected false to be true
```

I'm wondering why this is so?

Update based on answers:

```
def array_of_fixnums?(array)
  result = true
  array.each { |n| return false unless n.is_a? Fixnum }
  result
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

1. The problem is phrased in a slightly vague manner. What they actually want is for you to return false if any of the elements are not Fixnums, and true otherwise — so an empty array should give true. If you look at your code, you'll see that `result` starts out false, so if the array is empty, it will return false even though the test thinks it should be true. You can solve this by starting out with true.
2. Your code actually just detects whether the *last* element of the array is a Fixnum. Let's take the array `[1, "nope", 3]`. It will first see 1 and set `result` to true, then it will see "nope" and set `result` to false, then it will see 3 and set `result` to true, and that's what the method will return. RubyMonks tests actually don't detect this error, but it would show up in the real world. You want to return immediately after getting a false result, as that is enough to determine that the array is *not* all Fixnums.

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense. So why do we give an empty array the benefit of the doubt? it seems to be in quantum limbo, it is not an array of Fixnums, nor not an array of things that aren't Fixnums?

Comment: @cheshirecatalyst It's true, you could reasonably argue for both true and false there. All I can really say is that true is the traditional default for "all"-type algorithms, probably because it's the most obvious implementation. (Conversely, `any?` defaults to false, presumably for the same reason.)

Answer (score 0):

For this case you will never enter the each cycle as there are no elements in `array`. So you return the defualt value of `result` that you set to false on the line above. However if there are no elements in an array, then all of its elements are Fixnums and so you should return true.

Comment: Many thanks, i updated the code as per Chuck and your replies